# How can I access Windows files from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem

Is it possible to get the files I had on Windows onto my Ubuntu desktop?

How can I connect to my Windows partition from Ubuntu?

Comment: what kind of files?

Comment: It should be easy, is there any problem?

Answer (score 13):

yes of course you can acccess windows NTFS/FAT32 partitions from Ubuntu

From [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions):

> Using the File Manager For those using a desktop version of Ubuntu, or
>   one of its offical derivatives, the easiest and quickest way of
>   mounting NTFS or FAT32 partitions is from the file manager: Nautilus
>   in Ubuntu, Thunar in Xubuntu, Dolphin in Kubuntu and PCManFM in
>   Lubuntu. Simply look in the left pane of the file manager for the
>   partition you wish to mount and click on it - it will be mounted and
>   its contents will show up in the main pane. Partitions show with their
>   labels if labelled, or their size if not.
>
> Unless you require your Windows partition - or a NTFS/FAT32 partition
>   for data shared with Windows - mounted every time you boot up for one
>   of the reasons given below, mounting from the file manager in this way
>   should suffice.
>
> If you are using a Wubi version of Ubuntu and you wish to browse the
>   host partition, you do not need to mount it - it is mounted already in
>   the "host" folder. Click on "File System" in the left pane of the
>   Nautilus file browser and then open the host folder which you will see
>   in the main pane.

Just Open Home folder from your Dash menu and you can see all partitions mounted under **Devices**:

[image]

Click on the needed drive and copy files/folders thw way you want to your Ubuntu drive

Answer (score 8):

Yes, just mount the windows partition from which you want to copy files. Drag and drop the files on to your Ubuntu desktop. That's all.

Mounting a partition can be done manually or automatically,

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/windows
    # X = partition number
```

Now your windows partition should be mounted inside `/media/windows` directory.

After you clicked on the corresponding partition icon(which was on the unity), it get automatically mounted inside `/media/$USER` directory. To copy files from windows partition to Ubuntu desktop, you have to run these command,

```
cp /media/$USER/xxxxxxx/folder ~/Desktop
    # To copy a folder to your Ubuntu desktop

cp /media/$USER/xxxxxxx/folder/* ~/Desktop
    # To copy all the files inside that folder to Ubuntu desktop

cp /media/$USER/xxxxxxx/folder/filename ~/Desktop
    # To copy specific file to your Ubuntu desktop
```

`xxxxxxx` - label name of the Windows partition.

Comment: Please add example commands else your answer would be considered as comment.

Comment: Good. Now let the downvoters redecide.

Answer (score 1):

From the default file browser in Ubuntu, you can find `other locations`, by pressing it you can navigate to disk partitions, you can find a partition that looks something like: `/dev/nvme...` or `/dev/sata...` according to your disk type.

By mounting this directory you can access all your windows files.

N.B.: this is valid for any operating system other than windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and enter the two commands below:

```
cd /media/$USER/
ls
```

The folders you get correspond usually (windows 10) for g drive, f drive and c drive. Navigate to either of these and access your files.