# I can't see contents of my hard disk drive in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: windows, files, live-usb, 20.04

I'm trying ubuntu live with usb for the first time in a windows machine.

I am now in the ubuntu desktop and I want to explore my files in my hard disk which is separate from my boot drive.

I've gone to files folder and +other locations and have seen my hard disk but when I click it, only $recycle/bin and system volume information are present but I can't see the contents of my drive.

I would like to know how to view the files on this drive because I want to use linux more.  Thank you.

Comment: check this answer https://superuser.com/questions/376457/how-to-access-hd-contents-with-ubuntu-bootable-usb

Comment: Is your Windows properly shut down? Is fast startup off? If you have windows pro, is bitlocker enabled?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful, even though I'm not sure if it applies to Ubuntu from USB stick as well.

[How can I access Windows files from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433591/how-can-i-access-windows-files-from-ubuntu)

Let us know if it works. :)