# Mounting a Windows Share NTFS Drive: Ubuntu File Manager, "Passphrase Needed to Access Encrypted Data"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, encryption

I have installed **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** on dual boot with **Windows 11**. I let Ubuntu use only one of the four drives. Now in Ubuntu, the other three drives are showing in an encrypted form. When clicked, Ubuntu tries to mount them but it says, ***"A passphrase needed to access encrypted data"*** and requires a password. I have entered my own password which does not work.

**Note:** It is said in the link below that Ubuntu File Manager should be able to mount them.
https://askubuntu.com/a/433600/1631322

Now what is this Passphrase? How do I mount those other three drives from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Bitlocker disk encryption is enabled by default with Windows 11. By default, it's using the TPM, so it doesn't ask for a password at boot.

If you haven't already saved your bitlocker recovery key, do it, it's a long uppercase key with dashes, and you can use that as the passphrase when prompted from Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The required passphrase is a bitlocker encryption key (which was activated by default with the parallel Windows installation).
If you don't have it in your vicinity - no worries, you should be able to recover it [from here](https://myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list)

[image: Bitlocker devices]