# Accessing Win11 partition from Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, encryption, disk

I have a double-boot system with Win11 and Lubuntu. When trying to access the Win partition from Lubuntu it will not let me in, because it says the partition is encrypted "A passphrase is needed ...". Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: do `sudo apt install ntfs-3g`, reboot your computer, Mount using The Disks Application and you should be good to go. note that it can corrupt your windows partition as it Is experimental write support. Disable BitLocker if you have it turned on.

Comment: Bitlocker disk encryption is enabled by default with Windows 11. By default, it's using the TPM, so it doesn't ask for a password at boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429172/mounting-a-windows-share-ntfs-drive-ubuntu-file-manager-passphrase-needed-to

Comment: Use (Windows) BitLocker-encrypted drive on Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Maybe inside windows you will need to disable hybernate ...

run cmd.exe as admin

write:
powercfg.exe /hibernate off

reboot and try to access windows from lubuntu